# How to align my logo in center irrespective or left and right reference in relative layout?

Tags: android, layout, alignment

How can i align my logo in center without giving right or left reference in relative layout ? Is that possible ?

The Logo id is "windowtitle" and current alignment is something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#e7ebee"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="452dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#0a2436"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/back" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/inboxheader"
                android:layout_width="2dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back"
                android:background="#85929B"
                android:paddingBottom="15dip"
                android:paddingTop="15dip" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/windowtitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/inboxheader"
                android:background="#0a2436"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                android:paddingTop="10dip"
                android:src="@drawable/logo" >
            </ImageView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:dividerHeight="1dip"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:paddingTop="0dip" />

        <!-- android:divider="@color/listDivider" -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="bottom" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnManualLookup"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#4982AE"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:text="Activity"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
                    android:background="#85929B" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/supportbutton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#092435"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:text="Support"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
                    android:background="#85929B" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/messagebutton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#092435"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:text="Messages"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved your problem. I am new user in StackOverflow. It's very simple, I have copied your code and make comment of your said problem. Otherwise your code is same, don't worry I have also used same id what you have used. So, it's not hamper your code also.

Now the solve code with full layout is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#e7ebee"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="452dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#0a2436"
            >
          <!--<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/back" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/inboxheader"
                android:layout_width="2dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back"
                android:background="#85929B"
                android:paddingBottom="15dip"
                android:paddingTop="15dip" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/windowtitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/inboxheader"
                android:background="#0a2436"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                android:paddingTop="10dip"
                android:src="@drawable/logo" >
            </ImageView>-->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/windowtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/logo" 
                android:contentDescription="@null"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/back" />            
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/inboxheader"
                android:layout_width="2dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back"
                android:background="#85929B"
                android:paddingBottom="15dip"
                android:paddingTop="15dip" /> 
        </RelativeLayout>
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:dividerHeight="1dip"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:paddingTop="0dip" />
        <!-- android:divider="@color/listDivider" -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="bottom" >
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnManualLookup"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#4982AE"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:text="Activity"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
                    android:background="#85929B" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/supportbutton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#092435"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:text="Support"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
                    android:background="#85929B" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/messagebutton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#092435"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:text="Messages"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You copy and paste this XML layout to your project and enjoy . If my answer help you please support this answer.

Enjoy the code.

Comment: Thankyou very much Satyaki. I really appreciate your dedication and enthu...Keep going...

Comment: It's my pleasure that my little changes help you. I always love to do programming. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee you can also use attribute

**android:layout_centerInParent="true"**

Comment: @logosar Yaa, It will.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably make that `RelativeLayout` a `LinearLayout` and give each of those `View`s a `weight`. You might have to play with the `weight` a little to get exactly what you want but it should work. Something like

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0a2436"
        android:gravity="center"  // I don't think this is needed 
        android:orientation="horizontal" >  

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/back" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/inboxheader"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#85929B"
            android:paddingBottom="15dip"
            android:paddingTop="15dip" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/windowtitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="#0a2436"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I haven't tested this yet but you can try this and see if it gives you about what you need. As I said, you may need to play around with the `layout_weight` a little but this may get you close to what you want.

Comment: Thankyou codeMagic for putting an effort and your time, It was helpful